# Simple, jQuery Password Screen?

Tags: jquery, validation, passwords

In-between the upgrade to our company's bigger, better website that doesn't reek of the late 90's, I've been asked to implement something.

We need to display promotions on our site. We're a wholesaler, though. We don't want just anyone to see them. We can accept that competition will always find a way to sneak in and get pricing -- that's a known fact and common practice -- but we don't want just any random person to be able to click a link and see it. Security is not a HUGE issue for this one temporary instance.

This is a simple site with no form of user control/logins/no databases. Simple HTML. Built long before I was here.

SO, here's what I want to know how to do:

I'd like the user to click the "promotions" navigation button. It will bring them to a, let's say, promotions.htm link.

But upon this page loading, I want the first thing they see to be a div that covers the whole screen and everything behind it. I'd like for there to be a simple "Password" input field. Upon typing in the right password and clicking a button below, for this roadblock password div to vanish and grant them visual access to the content.

I've tried googling this to death, but am only met with links about how to validate password length/strength, or links about passwords in relation to proper databases and logins.

I don't need a ton of code; I'd like to think I can figure enough out on my own if I'm given a push or some starting ideas.

A possible problem here is the ability for people to just use something like Chrome's inspector and to hide the blocking divs/elements. Again, we know the password will get out and competition will eventually see some of it, but we don't want just anybody who knows how to hide a div in their browser to see it either.

Does anyone have an ideas how this (simple?) text field checker could be made?

Comment: Any data in HTML MUST be considered as public. Any logic to hide private data MUST be done server side

Comment: Thanks! I understand that it is not going to be secure, but that's why it's a temp fix until we have an entirely new site and can validate such things on the server. For this simple fix, we just need to hide "enough" so that the average computer user won't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on it, using some hilariously insecure password obfuscating with `.fromCharCode()`

(Hint: The password is "hunter2")

```js
var arr = [104, 117, 110, 116, 101, 114, 50];
var str = '';
arr.forEach(function (val, index) {
  str += String.fromCharCode(val);
})

$('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var pw = $(this).find('#password');
  
  if ( pw.val() == str ) {
    $('#fortknox').hide();
  }
  
})
```

```css
#fortknox {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:black;
  z-index: 100;
}

#fortknox form {
  display:block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/8Jne9VO.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fortknox">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
    <button type="submit">Enter</button>
  </form>
</div>
  
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I would have never thought to obfuscate the thing too, which is really common sense, because I've never been quite sure how. Love what you did with the key/character codes. Straight to the point. Thanks again!

Edit: What! You can preview compiled code on Stack now? Amazing. And it works perfect. You're the best.

Comment: No problem, was fun to make.